# Can somebody explains that why my input fields value is not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, split, words

I am making a simple word counter program in JavaScript. I am fairly new in JavaScript world so excuse me if I am asking an rudimentary and simple enough question. I'm getting everything working that the string of text from textarea is splitted into words array and i can log number of words to console but can't display them into a text field where I want them to appear. Hope that someone can help here. Thanks

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var numWords = document.getElementById("output");
var str = document.getElementById("txtBox");
btn.onclick = function()
{
   var words = str.value.split(" ");
   numWords.innerHTML.value = words.length;
   console.log( words.length );
   
};
```

```css
.container
{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

textarea
{
  width: 560px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input 
{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

input[type="submit"]
{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: #84ac49;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
    <div class="container">
        <from>
            <textarea name="txtBox" id="txtBox" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="text" value = 0 id="output">
            <input type="submit" value="Count Words" id="btn">
        </from>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script (JS) is not included in your page (HTML), neither is the CSS

Comment: I'm using jsbin.com so I think its automatically added to page or if itsn't then how do I do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move getting value in click function event

```
btn.onclick = function()
{
    var str = document.getElementById("txtBox").value
    var words = str.split(" ");
    numWords.value = words.length;
    console.log( words.length );

 };
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/muhammadusmaann/pvbshjo2/2/)

Comment: Thanks but that didn't added number of words into the input field.

Comment: excellent, I did work, many thanks for your help. would you please help to extend it so that I don't need button to count the words but rather as typing goes on the number of words keep updating in the output field? Thanks a lot

Comment: why not used innerHTML.value but just .value, can you explain?

Comment: because its input type not other tags

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.onclick = function () {
    var words = str.value.split(" ");
    numWords.value = words.length;
    console.log(words.length);
};
```

also you can set input like this:

```
<input value="Count Words" id="btn">
```

Answer (score 0):

when You click on count button You will get word count.

HTML

```
<textarea id="inputString" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="Convert" value="Count Words" onClick="countWords();"> 
    <input id="wordcount" type="text" value="0" size="6">
```

Javascript

```
 countWords=function(){
    s=document.getElementById("inputString").value;
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    document.getElementById("wordcount").value = s.split(' ').length;
}
```

Here is a demo :https://jsfiddle.net/DhwaniSanghvi/tdn3x72g/

Comment: Thanks but it looks a bit complex for me as I am only a beginner. Thanks again for your help